# How can I access a model from a controller using laravel4?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

How can I access a model from a controller using laravel4?

So far I have my controller:

```
<?php
class GatewayController extends BaseController {

public function getContentAll()
{
    $content = Content::getContentAll();
    return $content;

}
```

And my model:

```
<?php

class Content extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = '_content';

    public function getContentAll(){

        return 'test';
    }
```

But I get:

```
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
```

Comment: What error did you got exactly ?

Comment: First thing - you are doing a static call to the model's function whereas it is not declared as static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
$content = Content::getContentAll();
```

Try this:

```
$content = Content->getContentAll();
                  ^^
```

Or declare your function as `static`, like so:

```
public static function getContentAll(){

    return 'test';
}
```

---

**UPDATE**: if you don't want to have a `static function`, you should *instantiate* your class in order to call non-static functions:

```
$c = new Content();
$content = $c->getContentAll();
```

Comment: -> this does not work and I do not want to declare it as static

Comment: Thanks, just out of interest, which method would be better? Static or non-static? Why use one over the other?

Comment: Well I think @cuewizchris's answer is the way to go. You shouldn't put business logic in your model.

Comment: @simone and why is that ? It's not a missuse to follow the "slim-controller" philosophy, in which most of the Biz Logic is placed in the models.

Comment: I can't really say if the slim controller (or fat model) philosophy is good in Laravel; honestly I don't know much about it. However I think we should just try to follow Laravel's own philosophy.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, Eloquent handles the returning of a model collection. You do not need to handle this yourself. So your model should simply look like this:

```
class Content extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = '_content';

}
```

You can then simply get all your content using this:

```
$content = Content::all();
```

EDIT:

If you want to do stuff with the data in your model, try this:

```
class Content extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = '_content';

    public function modifiedCollection()
    {
        $allContent = self::all();
        $modifiedContent = array();

        foreach ($allContent as $content) {
            // do something to $content                  

            $modifiedContent[] = $content;
        }

        return $modifiedContent;
    }  
}
```

This should then work:

```
$content = Content::modifiedCollection();
```

Comment: Yes, I know, but I want to do something to the data before returning it to the controller. Which should be done in a model.

Comment: Your edited solution does not work either, it's basically the same code I have in my original question.

Comment: Well, perhaps you should set debug to true and tell us what the error message is. This should work unless something else is amiss.

Comment: @user1013512 mate take a look at the Eloquent Accessors/Mutators if you want to process data between being fetched from the DB and being transfered to the Controller (or whatever else). But one remark, this concernes columns/fileds not collections.

Comment: @Gadoma these won't process what I want to be processed

Comment: @user1013512 yeah I thought so, but still it's good to know that in terms of preprocessing data from model :)